# QT 5 Application Crashes With No Monitor

Tags: qt, qt5, xcb

I am running a Qt Desktop Application on CentOS 6.4 with Qt 5 Libraries.

When I start the application from VNC, as some of our servers do not have monitors, the application crashes. Starting from:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

I have tracked this down to a core file call qxcbconnection.cpp and the line:

```
xcb_create_window(m_connection, XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
                  m_connectionEventListener, m_screens.at(0)->root(),
                  0, 0, 1, 1, 0, XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_ONLY,
                  m_screens.at(0)->screen()->root_visual, 0, 0);
```

The problem is, if there is no monitor connected then, m_screens is empty, and therefore causes an "index out of bounds" error.

My question is: Is there a way to get around this, or perhaps mimic a monitor somehow?

Comment: Is it a GUI application??

Comment: Yes it is. With Pre-Qt5 versions I could use the same GUI application with both servers with and without monitors. I am hoping the same here.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a regression bug in Qt, as I don't find anything relevant in the [Qt4 to Qt5 changelog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/sourcebreaks.html) nor in the [QtApplication documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#details). IMHO it should not crash , and should just do unnecessary work (like in Qt4). However you can choose which type of instance you want to create. The doc gives an minimal example :

```
QCoreApplication* createApplication(int &argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        if (!qstrcmp(argv[i], "-no-gui"))
            return new QCoreApplication(argc, argv);
    return new QApplication(argc, argv);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QCoreApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));

    if (qobject_cast<QApplication *>(app.data())) {
       // start GUI version...
    } else {
       // start non-GUI version...
    }

    return app->exec();
}
```

Ps : note that `QApplication` underwent a major change behind the curtains, even if the API didn't change as much.

Comment: The only problem I have with using a non GUI version is that I can't use the built in settings menu or view the graphical meters and such. Of which is when displayed when I connect through vnc/teamviewer.